# Retrieve User Profile Passwords

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have installed a fresh copy of Windows on one of my systems.

Now I am trying to access some folder on network through Map Network Drive but it requires password authentication, but I don't remember the network login details.

My second system is already connected to network and accessing the network drive content.

How can I retrieve the network password from my second system so I can use it on the first system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the Windows credential manager on the original PC (via control panel). This securely stores all credentials.

Click on "Windows Credentials" and you will see all of the stored network credentials. However, the password is obscured. I've not tried it, but I believe the password can be retrieved using a tool such as [Nirsoft's Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html).